# Can't execute CreateAll.tt template in SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a CreateAll.tt template in a Visual Studio project. All the scripts I try to execute are correct - the template is tested on a different machine with SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition and it works perfectly fine.

On my computer with SQL Server 2012 Express instance however, i get the following error:

```
============== STDERR ==============
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. .
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. .
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..


============== EXITCODE ==============
1
```

I already tried the suggestions given here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Comment: Well, sounds like you haven't specified the server name correctly. Are you using `.` or `localhost` instead of `.\SQLEXPRESS` or `localhost\SQLEXPRESS`? Does your connection string have any nonsense about `AttachDbFileName` or user instances?

Comment: Actually I had forgotten to uncomment the correct connection string (I have 2 for each machine I'm working on). Now it's .\SQLEXPRESS but I keep getting the same error. The project has just SQL scripts and the connection string is in another project of the same solution. I don't have AttachDbFilename in the string.

Comment: I also tried disabling the Windows firewall. This didn't help either.

Comment: And have you tried connecting to `.\SQLEXPRESS` from any other approach, like SSMS or SQLCMD? Are you sure the service is running and that you've enabled remote connections?

Comment: Without a doubt, I didn't have any problems with SSMS whenever I used it. About SQLCMD - I tried the command in step 1 of the article I have given lik to and got the following output in the console: http://s17.postimg.org/ijt1x65db/sql.png
Remote connections are enabled.

Comment: Well, if SSMS works and Visual Studio doesn't, and this is all from the same machine, the only explanation could be that Visual Studio is not trying to connect to the right machine (possibly because it is not using the connection string you think it's using). Have you considered exporting the script from Visual Studio and running it from SSMS?

Comment: What do you mean by exporting from VS?

Comment: I'm guessing Visual Studio must have some way to show you or save the .sql script that runs the commands on the SQL Server...

Comment: I also tried using the wrong conn. string on the machine with Developer edition. It looks like it doesn't look at the connection string at the Web.config as the script again executes successfully. I'm out of suggestions about the SQL Server instance.